# Having trouble with CustomValidator that checks RadioButtonList and TextBox values in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, radiobuttonlist, customvalidator

I have a form with contains, among others, a TextBox called "wmi_cell_phone" and a RadioButtonList "wmi_send_sms". 
Basically, I need to create a validator that checks whether the value of the selected radio is "Y". If this is the case, then it checks if the TextBox value is empty or not. If it is empty, then it should notify the user to enter a value.

Here is my .aspx code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="wmi_cell_phone" runat="server" MaxLength="100" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="wmi_send_sms" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server" Width="140px" CssClass="radio"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and code-behind (VB):

```
wmi_send_sms.Items(0).Value = "Y"
wmi_send_sms.Items(1).Value = "N"
```

My validator

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="val_wmi_send_sms" runat="server"
ClientValidationFunction="ValidateSMS"
Display= "Dynamic"
ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid phone number."> </asp:CustomValidator>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">                  
function ValidateSMS(Source, args) 
{

  var smsRadio = document.getElementsByName('<%= wmi_send_sms.ClientID %>');
      var cellphone = document.getElementById('<%= wmi_cell_phone.ClientID %>');    

   for (var x = 0; x < smsRadio.length; x ++) 
   {
      if (smsRadio[x].checked) 
      {
          if (smsRadio[x].value == "Y") 
          {
              if (cellphone.value == "")
                   args.IsValid = false;
              else
                   args.IsValid = true;
          }
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Bu it doesn't seem to work.. Maybe I'm accessing the RadioButtonList in the wrong way..

Comment: What means `it doesn't seem to work`?
Do you have debugged the js-function? Post also the markup of your Validator.

Comment: I mean, it's not doing what it's supposed to do... if the user select the Radio with the value of "Yes", and leaves the TextBox empty, it should alert the user that he's supposed to enter a value in the TextBox.. but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Do you have debugged if the js-function is called? Use developer tools for ie: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535 or FireBug for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/

Answer (score 1):

You should first debug if the ClientValidationFunction gets called by the Validator.

- Use developer tools for ie: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535
- FireBug for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/

If the Validator should work even if nothing was selected you have to set [ValidateEmptyText](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQhgIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext.aspx&rct=j&q=customvalidator%20validatemeptytext&ei=dTDoTO7XC4qdOo-J4fwN&usg=AFQjCNEYaezdfoDtCtDPThustjQjYAgT8g&sig2=L_A-JqrjgtmrtJm6RxsiHg&cad=rja) to true.

- Does the ValidationGroup value match in all 3 places: the submit button, the validator control, and the control to validate?
- Does the submit button have CausesValidation=true?
- Does the RadioButtonList has **CausesValidation**=true?

Answer (score 0):

> "Maybe I'm accessing the
>   RadioButtonList in the wrong way.."

Yep.

Look at the markup generated, it will be something like this:

```
<table id="wmi_send_sms" class="radio" style="width:140px;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="wmi_send_sms_0" type="radio" name="wmi_send_sms" value="Y" />
      <label for="wmi_send_sms_0">Y</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="wmi_send_sms_1" type="radio" name="wmi_send_sms" value="N" />
      <label for="wmi_send_sms_1">N</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Your `<%= wmi_send_sms.ClientID %>` tag is getting the ID of the table enclosing the radio button list.

Personally, when working on the client side, I find it much easier to avoid `RadioButtonList`. Just create two `RadioButton` controls, using the `GroupName` property to associate them with each other.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="wmi_send_sms_y" runat="server" GroupName="wmi_send_sms" Text="Y" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="wmi_send_sms_n" runat="server" GroupName="wmi_send_sms" Text="N" />
```

Then you can check if the "Y" one is checked in your validator by accessing `<%= wmi_send_sms_y.ClientID %>`

Comment: Thanks Carson63000 for your input, I appreciate it! Unfortunately, I'm working on a existing project for a client at the company I work for. I can't change the design of the application (so I won't be able to change from RadioButtonList to RadioButton).. All I'm allowed to do is add the Validator to the existing code :( You know how it is!

Comment: Fair enough. OK, with a bit of fiddling, I couldn't find any super easy way to grab the client ID of an individual button inside a RadioButtonList. But <%= wmi_send_sms.ClientID %> gets you the table which you can look inside - ultimately, you'll need to find the actual <input type="radio"> elements and see which is checked. jQuery would make this a lot easier, if you can use that.

Comment: Alternatively, you *could* just assume that the ID of the first <input> will be the ClientID of the RadioButtonList with "_0" on the end of it; i.e. getElementsByName('<%= wmi_send_sms.ClientID %>_0') But I'm not 100% sure that this would be safe or guaranteed to never change.